# Postgresql: deleting duplicate records by CompanyID and CustomerID

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I can't get the following query to work.  It will work if I remove the last line of the query.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
DELETE FROM "ProjectMaster"
USING "ProjectMaster" ua2
WHERE "ProjectMaster"."EngagementName" = ua2."EngagementName" 
AND "ProjectMaster"."ProjectMasterID" < ua2."ProjectMasterID"
AND "CompanyID" = 490 and "ClientID" = 11125
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: @rich The error I was getting is:   ERROR:  column reference "CompanyID" is ambiguous

Comment: Well yes, you've aliased the column and then used companyid and clientid which exists on both (it's the same table). So you'd need to specify which table you want companyid and clientid from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your query in a fiddle, it gives me :

> error: relation "ProjectMaster" does not exist

Here are a few changes that can be done to avoid this error, without altering the logic (that you did not actually explain) :

- alias the table that you insert to (`ua1`)
- prefix the fields in the last line with the table they belong to (`ua1` or `ua2` ?)
- get rid of these noisy quotes

This runs without syntax error :

```
DELETE FROM ProjectMaster ua1
USING ProjectMaster ua2
WHERE 
    ua1.EngagementName = ua2.EngagementName
    AND ua1.ClientID = ua2.ClientID
    AND ua1.ProjectMasterID < ua2.ProjectMasterID
    AND ua1.CompanyID = 490 and ua1.ClientID = 11125;
```

Comment: You will not be able to run in fiddle.  The quotes are required in the tool I use which is Navicat and the DB is Postgres.

Comment: @Tim : yes, I understand. I did test in a Postgres fiddle though I did not paste the link in my answer. If you just add quotes to my query and run it, does it work as expected ?

Comment: To clarify. I'm trying to filter records by CompanyID and ClientID, but find duplicates in ProjectMaster table that have a duplicate EngagementNames. So each row in ProjectMaster has CompanyID, ClientID, EngagementName. –

Comment: Your query does run without error, but it deletes all records from the ProjectMaster table.  It should only delete the duplicates.                                    
6 records: 1040 Tax Prep, 1040 Tax Prep, Consulting, Consulting, Other, Other.  Of course each of these rows also have CompanyID 490 and ClientID 11125. 
This ClientID-11125 should be left with 3 records only.  Your query deleted all 6 records.

Comment: @Tim : I updated the query from your comments, please check

Comment: You nailed it GMB!  Thanks so much for taking the time.  This query is a life saver for me!  I tried to vote, but I'm new here and it would not take vote!

Comment: Thanks for informing me @GMB.  I'm new here.  Accepted - DONE.   I have found many answers here, but never posed a questions.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
DELETE FROM "ProjectMaster"
WHERE "CompanyID" = 490 and "ClientID" = 11125 AND
      "ProjectMasterID" < (SELECT MAX(pm2."ProjectMasterID" 
                           FROM "ProjectMaster" pm2
                           WHERE pm2."CompanyID" = "ProjectMaster"."CompanyID" AND
                                 pm2."ClientID" = "ProjectMaster"."ClientID"
                          );
```

That is, the correlation is to the company and client, not to something called engagement.  This is based on my interpretation of the title of your question.

Comment: Objective:  Find all duplicate records for CompanyID = 490 and ClientID 11125 and if the query finds 10 records, 5 good, 5 duplicate, that it will delete the 5 duplicate records.  I want to the option to either run query for an entire company or a specific Client.  This a multi-tenant database with many Companies, so I have to limit the records by Company.  Thanks for your quick response!!

Comment: To clarify.  I'm trying to filter records by CompanyID and ClientID, but find duplicates in ProjectMaster table that have a duplicate EngagementNames.  So each row in ProjectMaster has CompanyID, ClientID, EngagementName.